# ReactJS - Inline styling does not update upon rerendering of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've encountered an issue while trying to achieve a parallax style effect for one of my components. Currently, I am transforming the inline style by setting a scroll listener once the component mounts and changing the component state upon scroll. However, the inline style does not seem to change during re-rendering even though I have checked the output of the state in the render function and seems to have correct outputs. I tried checking previous answers, but I haven't been able to correct this issue.

Currently, my setup is as follows:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      style: {
        transform: 'translateY(0)'
      }
    };
    this.parallax = this.parallax.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.parallax);
  }

  componentWillUnMount() {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', this.parallax);
  }

  parallax() {
    function onScroll() {
      let scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
      this.setState({
        style: {
          transform: `translateY(${scrolled})`
        }
      });
    }

    if(window.pageYOffset < window.innerHeight) {
      window.requestAnimationFrame(onScroll.bind(this));
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="home-wrapper" style={this.state.style}>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

If anyone has any suggestions I will appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially it works fine because you have `translateY(0)` and in css 0 is fine without 'px' but once you update you are trying to do `translateY(35)` but css expects a px value so just change to `translateY(${scrolled}px)`

Comment: Oh of course! This minor bug kept me stumped for quite a while. Thank you very much.